# getting data by id from object

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is the code

The `peeps` object has the people detail like "Deen":

```
const peeps = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Deen',
    readerCategory: 'champ',
  },
  .
  .
  .
};
```

And the `chart` array has a combination of which peeps and the book ID the liked:

```
const chart = [
  {
    id: 1,
    peepsID: '1',
    bookLikedID: '1',
  },
  .
  .
  .
];
```

The `books` object has the book names like "Harry Potter Series":

```
const books = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Harry Potter Series',
  },
```

From this information, one of the list items might look like this:

```
* Deen's likes a Harry Potter Series book.
```

Comment: I hope you like the answer that I've provided, if you require any further explanation or anything along those lines, feel free to reply to this comment if you don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer I provided! :)

Comment: can u help me to find out that which peoples like the same book

Comment: I've written a function that will return an array of names form the `peeps` object, for all people that like the book that has the name that's given to the `similarTastes` function that I've made.

Comment: PS. I've also included `getAllSimilarTastes`.

Comment: can u help me with if no one like a particular book

Comment: I've included `getUnliked` and `isUnliked`, `getUnliked` returns an array of all books that no one has liked, then the `isUnliked` will accept the book name to state whether or not that particular book has been liked by at least one person, the logic being that `isUnliked` will return a Boolean as you're searching for a specific book.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like this, as you can see, we just iterate over the `chart` array, getting the relevant `id`, and returning a relevant string according to the `bookLikedID`, `peepsID` & `name` properties.

If you require some documentation, then I suggest you take a look at something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the rest should be relatively straightforward.

## Edit

If you want to know more about the syntax that I've decided to use, it's known as currying, if you'd like to read more into topics such as currying and functional programming, then an excellent source of information would be posts by [Eric](https://medium.com/@_ericelliott). I've found Eric to be an excellent source to learn how to implement functional style programming into JavaScript applications.

## Edit 2

People who like the same book(s), as requested, as you can see in this example the function takes one more argument, it simply takes the book name that you're querying. This function will then use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to generate an array of names that like book 'x'.

I've also used [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for the update to find all people that like `'x'` book.

```js
const peeps={1:{id:1,name:"Deen",readerCategory:"champ"},2:{id:2,name:"Tom",readerCategory:"noob"},3:{id:3,name:"Jack",readerCategory:"GOD"}};
const chart=[{id:1,peepsID:"1",bookLikedID:"1"},{id:2,peepsID:"2",bookLikedID:"1"},{id:3,peepsID:"3",bookLikedID:"2"}]; 
const books={1:{id:1,name:"Harry Potter Series"},2:{id:2,name:"Lord Of The Rings Series"},3:{id:3,name:"Fifty Shades of Grey"}};

// Edit
const results = a => b => c => a.map(o => `${b[o.peepsID].name} likes ${c[o.bookLikedID].name}`);

// Edit 2
const similarTastes = a => b => c => n => a.reduce((v, o) => {
  const found = Object.values(c).find(({name}) => name == n);
  if (found && o.bookLikedID == found.id) v.push(b[o.peepsID].name);
  return v;
}, []);

// Edit 3
const getAllSimilarTastes = a => b => c => {
  const obj = {};
  Object.keys(c).map(k => obj[c[k].name] = similarTastes(a)(b)(c)(c[k].name));
  return obj;
};

// Edit 4
const getUnliked = a => b => c => {
  const o = getAllSimilarTastes(a)(b)(c);
  return Object.keys(o).filter(x => o[x].length <= 0);
};

const isUnliked = a => b => c => n => getUnliked(a)(b)(c).indexOf(n) >= 0;

// Results.
console.log(results(chart)(peeps)(books));
console.log(similarTastes(chart)(peeps)(books)('Harry Potter Series'));
console.log(getAllSimilarTastes(chart)(peeps)(books));
console.log(getUnliked(chart)(peeps)(books));
console.log(isUnliked(chart)(peeps)(books)('Fifty Shades of Grey'));
console.log(isUnliked(chart)(peeps)(books)('Harry Potter Series'));
```